# Adding an Entity to an Azure Cosmos Table with Javascript Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

In Azure, I have a javascript HTTPTrigger Function App with:

```
const azure = require('azure-storage')
const tableSvc = azure.createTableService(
    process.env.COSMOS_TABLE_ACCOUNT,
    process.env.COSMOS_TABLE_KEY,
    process.env.COSMOS_TABLE_ENDPOINT
)
const entGen = azure.TableUtilities.entityGenerator
const testData = {
    PartitionKey: entGen.String('test'),
    RowKey: entGen.String(1),
    name: entGen.String('It works!')
}

const insertTestData = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    tableSvc.insertEntity('tests', testData, (error, res) => {
        if (error) return reject(error)
        resolve(res)
    })
})
...
```

I've confirmed that the environment variables are all set and populated with the values from Azure Cosmos DB -> Cosmos Table Instance -> Connection String.

I've also tried connecting with:

```
const tableSvc = azure.createTableService(
    process.env.COSMOS_TABLE_CONNECTION_STRING
)
```

When I call `insertTestData()`, I'm getting back an error back from the `.insertEntity` callback with an empty object: `{}`. No entities are being added to my `tests` table, as confirmed by the Data Explorer.

Any ideas how to perform this operation or get more information in my debugger? I have an Insight monitor attached to the process, but it reports a successful completion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that you're passing a numeric value for `RowKey` attribute.

```
RowKey: entGen.String(1)
```

When I used the code, it complained about that.

When I changed the code to:

```
RowKey: entGen.String('1')
```

I was able to insert the entity.

Here's my complete code:

```
const azure = require('azure-storage')

const tableSvc = azure.createTableService(
    'account-name',
    'account-key',
    'https://account-name.table.core.windows.net'
)
const entGen = azure.TableUtilities.entityGenerator
const testData = {
    PartitionKey: entGen.String('test'),
    RowKey: entGen.String('1'),
    name: entGen.String('It works!')
}

console.log(testData);

const insertTestData = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    tableSvc.insertEntity('test', testData, (error, res) => {
        if (error) return reject(error)
        resolve(res)
    })
})

console.log('----------------');

insertTestData()
.then((result) => {
  console.log('result');
  console.log(result);
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log('error');
  console.log(error);
})
```

I used `azure-storage` NPM package (version 2.10.2).

Comment: Brilliant. Those quotes around the number did it. You know, I thought about that last night, but I was looking at it thinking that the `.String()` method would cast to a string.